# Android com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID permission seems not taken into account?

Tags: flutter, android-permissions, google-advertising-id

I implemented the ad business model to my Flutter app.
Therefore I added the related permission as follows:

```xml
    <!-- bla bla -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <!-- the permission I added -->
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID"/>

</manifest>
```

in the `android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml` file and I also click 'Yes' in the app content section in the Play Store publisher console related section.

But, when I upload my app bundle to the console, I get an error stating (here is a translation as I get it in French):

> According to the Play Console advertising ID declaration, your app uses an advertising ID. A manifest file in your active artifacts does not include the com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID permission.

> If you don't include this permission in your manifest file, your advertising ID will be reset. This may impact your usage in advertising and analytics, and result in loss of revenue. Learn more

> You can remove these errors by updating your advertising ID declaration

> Advertising IDs of apps that target Android 13 (API 33) without AD_ID permission will be reset. This may impact your use in advertising and analytics. Learn more

TRying to remedy, I did `flutter clean` and also added the permission to the two others manifest files (those in debug and release) without effect.

What's wrong?